How to get a list of existing values for a specific attribute in Oxygen
I have a large xml file with many  tags that have a key attribute. It is a historical text, so there is orthographic variation and I need to normalize the keys.
I can see all the existing attribute values as suggestion in the CSS-suggestion pop-up, but I need to get a list with all the occurring values.
Example:
<xml>
<term type="Territory" key="Vireynato"/>
<term type="Territory" key="virreinato"/>
<term type="Settlement" key="Villas"/>
<term type="Settlement" key="Villa"/>
</xml>

Desired output: vireynato, virreinato, Villas, Villa
I need a solution in the software Oxygenxml to access the list of existing key values, not a programmatic solution. So, um, what I did was to search the menus and gui, but did not arrive.

It would be easier to provide an answer and provide concrete examples if you indicated the format of the file (tag has XML, so we can assume that) and a small example of the content and desired result. If it's just getting a distinct list of attribute values, there are a couple of ways to do that easily.

yes, it is xml. I will add examples. and yes, it is just getting a distinct list as you note.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML file sample.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
All within the question as text, no images.

The fastest and easiest way to produce a distinct list of attribute values is to apply an XPath to select them all and use the distinct-values() function.
distinct-values(//term/@key)

or if you want a single line CSV:
string-join(distinct-values(//term/@key), ", ")

You can do that easily in oXygen with the XML file open by applying the XPath in   either the XPath Toolbar, XPath Builder View, or by putting the XPath into an XQuery and switching to the XQuery Debugger perspective to execute against that XML and generate the output.

I now applied this to a set of large files, and I always get 112 distinct values - which probably means the first 112 values... Is this a known limitation?

Not at all. Change distinct-values() to count() and see how many items you are processing, or just return them all and see how many are selected.
